# AngularJS/Typescript - Access $http in unregisterd base service

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have multiple services, which all extend my `BaseService` class like so:

```
module app.services {
    export class PostService extends BaseService {        
        constructor() {
            super('post');
        }
    }

export var app:ng.IModule = app || angular.module('app.services.post');
    app.service('PostService', PostService);
}
```

In my `BaseService`, I will make requests using angularjs's provided `$http` tool. `BaseService` is not a registered angularJs Module (it's just a typescript class that my registered services extend):

```
module app.services {
    export class BaseService {

        protected $http: any;

        baseRoute:string;

        constructor(baseRoute:string) {

            if (baseRoute.indexOf('api/') === 0) {
                this.baseRoute = baseRoute;
            } else {
                this.baseRoute = 'api/' + baseRoute;
            }   
        }

       get(id: number) {
           this.$http.get...
       }
}
```

So `PostService` extends `BaseService`. How can I gain access to `$http` in this scenario? Ideally my `BaseController` will handle acquiring `$http` so all of it's child services don't have to send `$http` through. I just want to handle setting `$http` and using it in the `BaseController`. I feel like I should be able to inject it somehow:

`static $inject = ['$http'];`

But I haven't had any luck with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `bootstrap` function to get $injector and put it on window https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap.

Then use $injector.get('$http') anywhere you want in your code.

Comment: I have access to `$injector`. However, `$injector.get("$http")` returns an error: `Unknown provider: $httpProvider <- $http`. Why would the injector not be able to resolve `'$http'`?

Comment: My issue was here:

`protected _injector: angular.auto.IInjectorService = angular.injector(['ng']).get('$injector');`

I had left out the `['ng']`, but adding it in resolved the issue. Thanks for the help